# VLAN IP assigning

Tags: vmware-esxi, vlan

In an Esxi 5.0 server, we have a standard switch created with an ip range of 172.25.17.32-172.25.17.63 with subnet mask of 27. I have created some virtual machines in that host. Now I need to map these virtual machines to use a specific VLAN. I have created a VLAN in that switch having VLAN ID 1.

I am not sure how the IP ranges are assigned, if I have connected all the virtual machines to use VLAN ID 1. Can I manually assign an ip in the range between 172.28.1.1-172.28.1.256?

Can someone please tell me what happens when these VM's are connected to the VLAN ID 1 with respect to the IP's assigned.?

Comment: How have you assigned IP's?

Comment: Then I recommend that you grab a book about ESX or engage someone who knows this stuff. We don't do tutorials on serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task of assigning IP's is entirely up to you.
You can set them up statically, through DHCP, or through the vAPP feature in vSphere.

What "happens" to your virtual machine in VLAN ID 1 is:

- If you have static IP, it retains the static IP
- If you have DHCP, it depends if you have a DHCP server in that VLAN (or DHCP-Proxy)
- If you have vAPP's, it depends if you have set the "Associations" to the Port Group of that VLAN or not.

Comment: So, does that mean can I assign any ip in range 172.28.1.1-172.28.1.256?

Comment: If your network is configured properly sure, why not?